# "SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg" when passing arguments into function calls

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments

Passing an argument-provided value to a defined function seems impossible in my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
def setParams(params):
    retList=[]
    for param in params:
        retList.append(dict(actualParameterName=param,value=params[param]))
    return dict(parameters=dict(actualParameter=retList))

def runProcedure(procedure, project, invalidlyValidArguments):
    print(cmdr.httpPost(cmdr.makeEnvelope(
                        cmdr.createRequest('runProcedure',
                            dict(procedureName=procedure,
                                projectName=project,
                                setParams(params=invalidlyValidArguments)
    )))))

#Intended_Purpose=runProcedure(procedure='Build_Single_Module_For_Every_Config',project='My-module',validInvalidArgs={'moduleSelection':'Some_Handler','hakuna':'mattata'})
```

I expected this to evaluate cleanly, however I get

```
File "<ipython-input-34-c27d4a9b1a82>", line 19
setParams(params=invalidlyValidArguments)
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Even when I set line 19 to `setParams(invalidlyValidArguments)`, that yields the same error.

Comment: Make your code more readable and the problem will fix itself.

Comment: ```dict(procedureName=procedure,
                                projectName=project,
                                setParams(params=invalidlyValidArguments)``` The last argument in the dict constructor is missing a key

Comment: The problem is in your call to `dict`. The third item has no key name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to realize that my prior call to `dict()` already required a key-value pair. Python was not, as I assumed upset with my function call, but rather the fact that it could not interpret the output of the `setParams` into a key/value pair.

`setParams(params=invalidlyValidArguments)`
does not evaluate to a valid key pair for the underlying `dict()` call to evaluate.

I need to change

```
                            dict(procedureName=procedure,
                                projectName=project,
                                setParams(params=invalidlyValidArguments)#this is NOT a valid key-pair 
                            )
```

To something like

```
                            dict(procedureName=procedure,
                                projectName=project,
                                parameters=setParams(invalidlyValidArguments)
```

and have that `setparams` function remove one of its dictionary envelopes.